# Rails/ActiveRecord - Added a new attribute to my model but can't update it via PUT like the model's other attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

The title pretty much sums up the situation. I added a new attribute to my model but can't update it either via the a Rails-generated form or an Ajax request. (I can, however, update it via Rails console.) I can, however, update the model's other properties as one might expect. Does anyone have an idea as to why this might be happening? Again, the only change is the addition of a new attribute to my model via a migration.

Migration 1

```
class AddNumberToUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :users, :number, :integer
  end
end
```

Migration 2

```
class ChangeNumberDataTypeToStringInUser < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    change_column :users, :number, :string
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you add the new attribute in the `params.require(:user).permit()` in your controller?

Rails 4 introduced strong parameters. [Read more about it here](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#strong-parameters)